# ActionBar hamburger icon not working on API 16 (4.1)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I followed this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

And I implemented a nice beautiful actionbar with a hamburger icon and back button and it works great on most of my devices (5.0, 5.1, 4.4) - **but it doesn't work on one of devices running Android 4.1** (Samsung Galaxy S3 mini).

The code is pretty much as it is in the example link above. Here are some snippets that are probably more important.

Constructor: (ic_menu_with_padding is a styled version of my hamburger icon)

```
_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    activity,
    _drawerLayout, 
    R.drawable.ic_menu_with_padding, 
    R.string.drawer_open_accessiblity, 
    R.string.drawer_close_accessiblity
)
_drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_with_padding);
activity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
activity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I use `_drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true/false)` when switching between back button and hamburger based on which fragment is loaded.

One all my devices except one - it shows a hamburger menu and back button. On my device with API 16, it only shows a dark gray back button *all the time* (doesn't switch between hamburger/back). It looks just like the one in this picture on the left:

[image]

Any idea why the icon isn't working on this device/API?

Note: I am aware that this code utilizes the deprecated v4 ActionBarDrawerToggle library - but I'd like to see if there's a way to fix this issue with the v4 library since I have some dependencies that I'm unable to change just yet.

Comment: Can you confirm your imports? You are using the v4 drawertoggle which is deprecated.

Comment: @Skynet - yes, I'm using v4 ActionBarDrawerToggle and I am aware it's deprecated - but we currently have some dependencies to the v4 library that I'm not at liberty to change just yet. I realize this problem may be fixed in the v7 library, but I was hoping to see if there was a way to fix this issue in the v4 library without upgrading. I'll update the question to clearly state that.

Comment: v7 library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part of this library's classpath. You might want to check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) as well

Comment: That is for v7 appcompat library